# How do i create a custom document property in excel so that i can auto populate with a SharePoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am setting up an automatic document generator on our department's SharePoint site - users will submit the necessary details via a SharePoint list and the workflow will run automatically in the background to generate the three documents namely; specification (word doc), clearance form (word doc) and requisition form(excel).   I have managed to auto-populate the first two forms.  However, i am not able to do the same for the third file, which is an excel file.

I understand that there is no insert function for document property and tried following this particular advise but i couldn't get it to work. https://superuser.com/questions/99386/excel-cell-value-as-excel-document-metadata-property

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

By default, SharePoint uses Word file template as the default template of Document content type.

If you want to create an excel file by using SharePoint Designer workflow, you can create a custom Document Type (in my testing, it is named "Excel Content Type")and set Document Template to an Excel file:
[image]
Then add the custom Document into your library, then use "Create List Item" to create an Excel file using the custom content type:
[image]

After the workflow runs, the result is like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps.  I wasn't exactly clear in my earlier question. In fact, I am struck at inserting custom fields in the excel template, thus the earlier web link in my question.  I would appreciate if you have any insights to the above.  Thank you again!